# Making changes to CSV and writing to a new file

Tags: python, csv

I have a CSV file (students_temp.csv) with 7 columns and 20 rows:

```
Name,Age,Gender,Varsity,GPA,Town,State
John,18,Male,yes,3.2,Tacoma,WA
Tyler,18,Male,yes,2.9,Tacoma,WA
Jane,17,Jane,yes,3.5,Tacoma,WA
Michelle,18,Female,no,3.1,Tacoma,WA
Jamie,17,Male,no,2.6,Tacoma,WA
Robert,17,Male,yes,4.0,Tacoma,WA
Danielle,18,Female,no,3.0,Tacoma,WA
Dustin,18,Male,no,3.2,Tacoma,WA
Angela,16,Female,no,2.9,Tacoma,WA
Barbara,17,Female,yes,3.5,Tacoma,WA
Megan,18,Female,no,3.4,Tacoma,WA
Michael,18,Male,yes,3.0,Tacoma,WA
Craig,17,Male,no,3.1,Tacoma,WA
Jackson,18,Male,no,2.8,Tacoma,WA
Bill,18,Male,yes,3.2,Tacoma,WA
Matthew,17,Male,yes,3.0,Tacoma,WA
Karen,16,Female,no,3.4,Tacoma,WA
Sarah,17,Female,yes,3.2,Tacoma,WA
Charles,18,Male,no,3.5,Tacoma,WA
```

I would like to read the file, parse the Varsity column and change everything in that column to uppercase then write the entire CSV file with the included changes to a new CSV file (students.csv).

Here's what I have so far but it's not iterating through the entire column:

```
import csv

input_file = csv.DictReader(open('students_temp.csv', 'rb'))

for row in input_file:
    varsity_col = str(row['Varsity'])
    varsity_col.upper()

print varsity_col.upper()
```

Comment: Show your attempted code please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the code:

```
with open("/path/to/new/file", "w") as newfile:   # Create and open the new file
    with open("/path/to/old/file") as oldfile:    # Open the old file
        oldfile = oldfile.readlines()             # Read the lines of the old file into a list
        newfile.write(oldfile[0])                 # Write the column names to the new file
        for line in oldfile[1:]:                  # Iterate through the lines, skipping the first (which we already wrote to the new file)
            line = line.split(",")                # Split the line by commas
            line[3] = line[3].upper()             # Make the Varsity column value uppercase
            newfile.write(",".join(line))         # Put the line back together with .join and write it to the new file
```

And what the new file will look like:

```
Name,Age,Gender,Varsity,GPA,Town,State
John,18,Male,YES,3.2,Tacoma,WA
Tyler,18,Male,YES,2.9,Tacoma,WA
Jane,17,Jane,YES,3.5,Tacoma,WA
Michelle,18,Female,NO,3.1,Tacoma,WA
Jamie,17,Male,NO,2.6,Tacoma,WA
Robert,17,Male,YES,4.0,Tacoma,WA
Danielle,18,Female,NO,3.0,Tacoma,WA
Dustin,18,Male,NO,3.2,Tacoma,WA
Angela,16,Female,NO,2.9,Tacoma,WA
Barbara,17,Female,YES,3.5,Tacoma,WA
Megan,18,Female,NO,3.4,Tacoma,WA
Michael,18,Male,YES,3.0,Tacoma,WA
Craig,17,Male,NO,3.1,Tacoma,WA
Jackson,18,Male,NO,2.8,Tacoma,WA
Bill,18,Male,YES,3.2,Tacoma,WA
Matthew,17,Male,YES,3.0,Tacoma,WA
Karen,16,Female,NO,3.4,Tacoma,WA
Sarah,17,Female,YES,3.2,Tacoma,WA
Charles,18,Male,NO,3.5,Tacoma,WA
```

That should be everything you want.